# Read Data from Snowflake through Snowpark and then insertion into folder on local machine with .csv format using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is code I have to query from snowflake but I am not able to write the pulled data into csv on local machine folder. I am getting

> snowflake.snowpark.dataframe has no attribute csv.

```
snowspark = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()

query = "select  * from tableCustomers"
df = snowspark.sql(query).collect()

df.write.csv("/data/dbstorage/offloads_da/testing_files/",header = 'true',sep='^', mode="overwrite")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to convert it into a pandas dataframe and then write it to csv :

```
df = df.to_pandas()
df.to_csv(path, header='true', sep='^', header=True, index=False)
```